# When someone behaves as if you owe them somthing

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for an idiom, expression, or simply an adverb which means act *as if other people owe you something while they're not* so while you're like this, you look at them or behave toward them from a demanding position which you reasonably shouldn't.

> After knowing about us rating him poorly, our teacher came in staring at us *as if we owe him something!* You didn't do your job mate! What were you expecting?!
>
> The superintendent complained about corridors being dirty *as if we owe him something*. Interestingly, he never hired someone to clean up the place!
>
> Why are you looking at me *as if I owe you something*. I was exhausted last night; I couldn't come over to help you with your homework.

Comment: "as if we owe him something" is actually a very good idiomatic phrase itself.

Comment: I agree with stangdon. The idiomatic phrase you are looking for is precisely, "as if we owe him something". Your question is a bit like asking "What is an idiomatic way of saying that a bird in the hand is worth two in the bush" :-) Stangdon, why not convert your comment to an answer, because I think it pretty much nails it.

Comment: @stangdon. Interesting! I googled it first and it didn't give much results and I figured it might not be the way English speakers say that; usually when this is an idiom it clearly shows up on top. Anyway, Is the usage in all sentences correct?

Comment: @Yuri -- the usage is not completely correct.  Since you _don't_ owe him anything, the clause is counter-factual, so the verb is in [the subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive): "as if I _owed_ you something."  The subjunctive is the same as the simple past, except the verb _to be_, which is _were_ in the subjunctive.  "If I _were_ president [which I'm not], I would legalize marijuana."

Comment: @Malvolio thank you. So I have to just replace _owe_ with _owed_. Then, there will be nothing wrong with the meaning and I'll have a natural sentence that a native speaker might use. Am I right?

Comment: @Yuri -- actually, native speakers often get this wrong.  Proper use of the subjective will mark you as someone you learned English in school, rather than just picking it up as a child.  I once got into a taxi in Boston and asked the driver to take me somewhere I could get [scrod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrod); he complimented me on my mastery of the pluperfect.

Comment: @Malvolio ur point well made :-) although people wont pick at me for using _owe_ but _owed_ is the right form. thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on who you ask, you've already got it - *as if X owe(s) them something* is idiomatic, though some say that it should be *as if X owed them something*. Most people won't bat an eyelid at the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases a person may feel that they are **entitled to** certain benefits or deference because of their status or position.

> An entitlement is the right to a particular privilege or benefit,
> granted by law or custom. You have a legal entitlement to speak to a
> lawyer if you're ever arrested and put in jail.
>
> Your entitlement program at work might offer various benefits, or you
> might receive a medical entitlement once you reach a certain age.
> These are just basic things you get. More recently, entitlement has
> taken on a critical sense. If someone has a sense of entitlement, that
> means the person believes he deserves certain privileges — and he's
> arrogant about it. The term "culture of entitlement" suggests that
> many people now have highly unreasonable expectations about what they
> are entitled to. ([vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/entitlement))

**Entitlement** :
2: belief that one is deserving of or entitled to certain privileges [(m-w.com)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entitlement)